TailwindMerge. How to extend text color?
I have tailwind config with extended color shade:
const config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        gray: {
          450: '#8e95a2'
        },
      }
     }
   }
}

When I merge text-gray-450 with twmerge util this new class just disappears in resulting classlist.
How can I properly extend twmerge to fix this?
I've tried this approach, but it didn't help:
const twMerge = extendTailwindMerge({
  extend: {
    classGroups: {
      'text-color': [{ text: [{ gray: ['450'] }] }]
    }
  }
})


Seems to work fine without needing to call extendTailwindMerge() as evidenced by this JSFiddle. Please consider providing an example of where the merging does not work as expected.

Yes, you are right, everything works. Apparently, there was some kind of glitch in the work of the code builder or something else. Now, after rebooting all the apps, everything works as it should. Perhaps I was too hasty with the question. Thanks for reply.
